# regex extract in hive for the following scenario?

Tags: java, sql, regex, hadoop, hive

In hive I need to split the column using regex_extract on "/" and then pick the 3rd value for eg: products/apple products/iphone in this case it is iphone, if there is no 3rd value then we need to fallback on the 2nd value which is apple products? plz guide me on achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

input.txt

```
products/apple products/iphone
products/laptop
products/apple products/mobile/lumia
products/apple products/cover/samsung/gallaxy S4


hive> create table inputTable(line String);                                   
OK
Time taken: 0.086 seconds
hive> load data local inpath '/home/kishore/Data/input.txt'           
    > into table inputTable;                                          
Loading data to table default.inputtable
Table default.inputtable stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=133]
OK
Time taken: 0.277 seconds
hive> select split(line,'/')[size(split(line, '/'))-1]  from inputTable;      
OK
iphone
laptop
lumia
gallaxy S4
Time taken: 0.073 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply kishore but when i tried your method i'm getting a error  as
FAILED: SemanticException 1:44 Non-constant expressions for array indexes not supported. Error encountered near token '1' and also the value of 4th row should be cover right ?